# Using ${} around labels and divs

Tags: html, angularjs, label

I've come across some html code where certain labels, divs, spans are surrounded by ${}.  For example:

```
<label>${Related Lists}</label>
```

I've googled around, but can't seem to find any explanation on why or when to use ${}.  Can anyone provide some guidance on this?

Comment: This appears to be some sort of templating language, it isn't something baked into angular hence not seeing it anywhere.  You'd have to see what templating language(s) the given project is using, give a link to a specific project and can check it out.  (in general there is "twig", "handlebars", "blade", etc. in terms of templating languages) you can also use ${someVar} in template strings in ES6+

Comment: JavaScript formatting placeholders (similar to Python): `a=10; \`number:${a}\`` -> `"number:10"`. They were probably used in some template

Comment: To clarify too, angular 1.x uses `{{}}` curly braces for `interpolation` or templates.

Comment: ahh ok thanks, will look into templates.

Comment: @theIronLotus AngularJS populates templates with `{{ a }}` syntax as long as they are bounded to scope in the controller. E.g. `$scope.a = 10;` -> `<label>{{a}}</label>`

Comment: Thanks @AlekseySolovey, yea this is different it only has single brackets which was confusing me.

Comment: Me and a co-worker implemented a vanilla javascript template binder. We used to use really weird and unique stuff to populate the templates with data, and this reminded me of our engine. This may be a custom made databind engine, I've made some research and found nothing on this as well.

Comment: @F.Almeida it's [pure javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey never used this before. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax in ServiceNow's platform is used for internationalization